# How to reduce haze while photographing lost distance mountains?

Tags: image-quality, landscape, haze

When I go hiking I noticed that sometimes the photos have a noticeable amount of haze, especially when photographing long distance mountains.
I think this is a natural phenomenon due to air composition, but I was wondering whether I can reduce this effect somehow.

After reading some guides, I tried with polarizer filters, but it did not really improved much. In Lightroom I can "Dehaze" the photos, but this introduces an overall blue tonality that makes the overall composition unreal.
How is it possible to take "cristal clear" shots of mountains? Is it a matter of time/weather conditions (like better when cloudy/more humid than a sunny day)?

Comment: Related: [How can I take pictures of far-away mountains to the South?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6580/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am extending contrast and saturation in GIMP.

In Lightroom there are other options as well. Beginning with auto tone, up to manipulation on vibrancy, but you can stick to contrast and saturation. In case when haze is more blueish you can tune also white balance.